# How to show current location in android mapview with accuracy?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am working on an android geolocation app. In that I have added marker at current position in map and I have set accuracy as 10 meters but only sometimes it shows accurate current location otherwise it shows next building to current building. I am using `NetworkProvider` for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use GPS Provider, typically its more accurate than Network provider. Network provider uses cell-id loation to track your position